# Convergence of Kaprekar's constant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, recreational-mathematics

I have been looking into the proof behind why 6174 is the unique 4 digit number that has the property that the difference between the digits arranged in ascending and descending order is the same number, however I cannot get my head around proofs that show that the rest of 4 digit numbers may converge to that value - why can we not get stuck in a recurring cycle for example? A lot of the literature I came across online seems very much to be proof by exhaustion as there is only a finite number of cases, but does anyone have a more elegant proof?

Comment: See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar%27s_routine#Definition_and_properties

Comment: We do get stuck in a different cycle when we start with 3333, for instance.